# Timer function won't take in additional arguments

Tags: python

I want to time this searching algorithm using something I found on the internet

```
L=[8,2,1,111,8,3,4,6,5,7,10,9,12,11]
v=10

def searchlinear(L, v):
          
    i= 0
    for value in L:
        if value == v:
            return i
        i+= 1
    return len(L)


from random import randint
from timeit import repeat

def run_algorithm(algorithm, array):
  
    setup_code = f"from __main__ import {algorithm}" \
        if algorithm != "sorted" else ""

    stmt = f"{algorithm}({array})"

    times = repeat(setup=setup_code, stmt=stmt, repeat=3, number=10)

    print(f"Algorithm: {algorithm}. Minimum execution time: {min(times)}")

ARRAY_LENGTH = len(L)
array = [randint(0, 1000) for i in range(ARRAY_LENGTH)]

run_algorithm(algorithm="searchlinear", array=array)
```

Somehow, it shows up this error:

> TypeError: searchlinear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'

I feel like I have to remove the `v` argument in my function, but I need that for it to work. Any tips?

Comment: Aside from passing the wrong parameters, you're timing the list construction. You should put that in the setup.

Comment: Okay, so `array = [randint(0, 1000) for i in range(ARRAY_LENGTH)]` is the array that you want to be searched, when the test runs. **What value** do you want to search for? *How is the code intended to explain that*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `searchlinear` function expects 2 arguments. But, in the following line, you only passed the array. You have to pass the second argument too:

```py
stmt = f"{algorithm}({array})"
```

So, change it to something like:

```py
someValue = 7  # any number you want to search
stmt = f"{algorithm}({array}, {someValue})"
```